# perl XML Convert Solution

Tags: xml, perl, parsing, cpan, perl-module

I'm a beginner for Perl and CPAN Modules

I wanna convert a xml file include:

```
<Item><Link>http://example.com/</Link></Item>....
```

To

```
<Item><Link>http://mysite.com/</Link></Item>....
```

Do you have smart solutions ? with **CPAN Module**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- see [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.37/Twig.pm) - A perl module for processing huge XML documents in tree mode.
- or [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.18/lib/XML/Simple.pm) - Easy API to maintain XML (esp config files)

like,

```
use strict;
use warnings; 
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;

my $xml = q~<?xml version='1.0'?>
<root>
  <Item>
  <Link>http://example.com/</Link>
  </Item>
  <Item>
   <Link>http://example1.com/</Link>
  </Item>
</root>~;

print $xml,$/;

my $data = XMLin($xml);

print Dumper( $data );

foreach my $test (@{$data->{Item}}){
   foreach my $key (keys %{$test}){
       $test->{$key} =~ s/example/mysite/;
   }
}
 print XMLout($data, RootName=>'root', NoAttr=>1,XMLDecl => 1);
```

output:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<root>
  <Item>
  <Link>http://example.com/</Link>
  </Item>
  <Item>
   <Link>http://example1.com/</Link>
  </Item>
</root>
$VAR1 = {
          'Item' => [
                    {
                      'Link' => 'http://example.com/'
                    },
                    {
                      'Link' => 'http://example1.com/'
                    }
                  ]
        };
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<root>
  <Item>
    <Link>http://mysite.com/</Link>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Link>http://mysite1.com/</Link>
  </Item>
</root>
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution using XML::Twig is below. Compared with the XML::Simple option it works no matter where the `Link` elements are in the XML, and it will respect the original formatting of the file. It will also work if the XML contains mixed-content.

If you need to change the file in place, you can use `parsefile_inplace` instead of `parsefile`, and I suspect the regular expression in `subs_text` may need to be improved in real life, but this code should be a good starting point.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

XML::Twig->new( twig_roots => { Link => \&replace_link, }, # process Link
                twig_print_outside_roots => 1,             # output everything else
              )
          ->parsefile( 'my.xml');

sub replace_link
  { my( $t, $link)= @_;
    $link->subs_text( qr{^http://example\.com/$}, 'http://mysite.com');
    $t->flush;               # or $link->print, outputs the modified (or not) link
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is changing a specific value, you don't really need anything special, you can simply use regexp:
from command line :

```
perl -pi -e 's@http://example.com/@http://mysite.com/@g' file.xml
```

**edit** : adding full code version :

```
my $file = '/tmp/test.xml';

open IN, "<$file" or die "can't open $file $!";
open OUT, ">$file.tmp" or die "can't open $file.tmp $!";
foreach (<IN>) {
    s@http://example.com/@http://mysite.com/@g;
    print OUT $_;
}
close(IN);
close(OUT);

rename("$file.tmp", "$file")
```

Comment: +1 for specifying a regular expression solution knowing full well the XML religious bigots will punish you mercilessly! The trick to being an open-minded and useful system administrator is knowing when to use a simple solution and when to use the heavy weight one (so few XML fans have any idea that simple solutions do occasionally suffice).

Comment: Thank you :), it's exactly how I feel about xml, sometimes you just don't need a full XML library to modify something like this.

Comment: The thing is, we don't have much information about the rest of the XML. For all we know it may include other elements that contain URLs. Or it may include them in the future. That's why I'd rather give a solution that's correct in any case.